# Why $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)q^{n/d}= \sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d)q^d$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, mobius-function

I was working on proving Gauss' formula for the number of monic irreducible polynomials of degree d over a finite field of order q. However, me (and Serge Lang himself in his book) came up with the formula (where N(d) is number of irreducible monic polynomials of degree d): $$N(n)=(1/n)\sum_{d|n}  \mu(d)q^{n/d},$$ however it seems that the common result is

$$N(n)=(1/n)\sum_{d|n}  \mu(n/d)q^d.$$ Could someone please show me how it is that the two results are equal to each other? Thank you.

Comment: $$\sum_{d \mid 10} f(d) g(10/d) = f(1) g(10) + f(2) g(5) + f(5) g(2) + f(10) g(1) \\ = f(10) g(1) + f(5) g(2) + f(2) g(5) + f(1) g(10) = \sum_{d \mid 10} f(10/d) g(d)$$

Comment: I suppose you mean $N(n)$ rather than $N(d)$?

Comment: This equivalence is used in a proof by Apostol, where he notes that if $d$ runs over all the factors of $n$, so does $\frac nd$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes I meant N(n) sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make a change of variables in the summation.  If you let $e=n/d$, then $d=n/e$ and $e$ will range over all divisors of $n$ as $d$ ranges over all divisors of $n$.  Thus $$(1/n)\sum_{d|n}  \mu(d)q^{n/d}=(1/n)\sum_{e|n}  \mu(n/e)q^{e}.$$ Renaming the dummy variable back to $d$, this gives equality of your two expressions.